# UDP server vs .NET for python for Unity

Tags: c#, python, .net, unity-game-engine, ironpython

Does anyone have an idea of the performance difference between .NET for python and just setting up a UDP server for communication between python and Unity? I've tried ironPython but it only supports python2 which is dead now. I need to run python functions for each agent I instantiate in Unity and grab their states as they update to animate in real time.

Comment: You are adding another layer of software be making a UDP connection.  The performance will depend on the size of the data being transferred, the number of transactions, and the speed of the machines (if two different machines are being used).

Comment: Did you simply try?